# OpenWhisk error "The action produced a response that exceeded the allowed length"

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I have an OpenWhisk action (on IBM Bluemix) which returns a large json document. I'm receiving an error indicating that the returned document is greater than 1048576 bytes (1MB). Is there a way to increase this limit ?

Thanks in advance -- Simon

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you could store the object to S3 or similar and the return a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

This page indicates the default limits and it seems it can can't be changed https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_reference.html#openwhisk_reference

Answer (score 0):

the recommendation for large payloads (>1MB) is to store them on sth like cloudant and then have cloudant fire a trigger to invoke an action. See here for details: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_cloudant.html#openwhisk_catalog_cloudant

Comment: Thanks Michael. Actually, thats exactly what I am doing :-) I read the doc from cloudant, do some processing, add some additional attributes, and then write the doc back to cloudant. Problem is, some of the docs are larger than 1MB.
It looks like I need to be smarter in what I'm reading/writing in order to get below the 1MB limit.

Comment: Hi Simon...hm, that is strange. You should be able to put documents >1MB into cloudant and also read them from within your OW action code. Where specifically are you hitting a a1MB limit?